# SSRS - Sharing same header in two tables

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a report where I need to display two tables (that actually have the same data but with diferent columns) one after the other, vertically, and share the same header between them.
This header has dynamic data, so I can't use the report header section.

I've tryed to put my two tables inside another table but as I can't have detail members inside other detail memeber, the header does not get repeated when data breaks into diferent pages.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would split this into three reports:
1. Master report, with two subreport objects pointing at...
2. Subreport 1, containing the 1st table
3. Subreport 2, containing the 2nd table